# Dúvida função JavaScript gerando PostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Estou com esta função no meu sistema, que limpa os campos, e atualiza o grid:

```js
 $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //cancela o comportamento padrão do link
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mask, .window').hide();
    document.location.href = '';
    document.getElementById("<%= txtid_recebimento.ClientID %>").value = '';
    document.getElementById("<%= txtidReceita.ClientID %>").value = '';
    document.getElementById("<%= modalExercutar.InnerText %>").value = 'Cadastrar Contas a Receber';
    GridRecebimento();
});
```

Essa função fica no X (fechar) do modal, porém na minha página tem várias tabs, e quando eu clico e executa a função, gera postback na página, e perde a tab selecionada. Quando eu tiro a limpeza dos campos, ela não gera o postback. Como posso fazer para que esta função não gere o postback de toda a página? Já tentei de várias formas que vi no fórum, porém nenhuma foi viável.

Comment: Aqui não é um fórum. Fora isso, se esse clique gera um post, então o código que gera o post deve estar na função `GridRecebimento`. Poderia editar a pergunta para adicionar o código dessa função?

Comment: Não pesquisei somente aqui Renan, pesquisei em vários lugares. eu fiz o teste tirando o GridRecebimento e o PostBack ocorreu da mesma forma. Creio que o problema não seja nele então.

Comment: Então talvez o trecho `e.preventDefault();` não esteja cancelando o evento de fato. Eu sei que isso funciona em alguns navegadores, mas não em outros. Deixe essa linha aí, mas adicione `event.returnValue = false;`

Comment: Adicionei Renan,  e.preventDefault();
                                            event.returnValue = false; coloquei logo abaixo do e.preventDefault(); Porém ocorre a mesma coisa, a função ocorre, porém não queria q realizasse o postback da pagina!